# YA short story about crowd control terrorism with black an white images, set in elementary school, part of anthology

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, dystopia

images that look like QR codes used to scramble peoples' brains, make them lose sight temporarily and maybe make them hear a piercing noise?

kids going through halls of school wearing sunglasses/blinders

something about black, dark, blackout? part of an SF YA anthologyi found at the library in early 2000's, maybe Firebirds? Author i think is male. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Different Kinds of Darkness* by David Langford. Summary from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLIT_%28short_story%29):

> ... a post-apocalyptic world where BLIT images are everywhere, and
>   millions have already been murdered by terrorist attacks utilizing
>   them. Television and the internet have been outlawed due to the
>   proliferation of BLIT images. In order to protect children, special
>   chips have been planted in their brains that creates a subjective and
>   artificial darkness (which the children call "type-two darkness") to
>   obscure any possible BLIT image they may inadvertently look at. The
>   main characters, all school children, form the "Shudder Club", where
>   they take turns looking at a BLIT image to see how long they last in
>   an effort to vaccinate themselves against them.

Edit: and [this](http://www.ansible.co.uk/books/dkod.html), I think, is the anthology.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had no idea there were related stories, that's awesome.